# Strange behavior with scrollIntoView on my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, js-scrollintoview

I'm just finishing my website made with react and typescript and I noticed weird behavior of my navbar. I use element.scrollIntoView to move screen to specific part of the website using element's id but sometimes it scrolls just a little bit down and that's it but in most of the cases it works just fine.

Website is live here: 
https://neidz.github.io/photography_agency/

Part of the code responsible for scrolling is here: 
https://github.com/Neidz/photography_agency/blob/master/src/Sections/Navbar/navbar.tsx

To replicate that behavior just click on any of the buttons in navigation at the top and it should happen in maybe 3 tries.